# User Input Validation Errors (Java)

Tags: java, algorithm

```
package javahistogramtwo;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class JavaHistogramTwo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int sum = 0;
        int count = 0;
        int mark = 0;
        int largest = 0, smallest = 0;
        int rangeOne = 0, rangeTwo = 0, rangeThree = 0, rangeFour = 0;

        System.out.println("Enter marks, -1 to finish: ");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

// Enter range validation
        {
            {                
                 while (!in.hasNextInt()) {
                    System.out.println("Input not valid");
                    in.next();
                }

                while (mark != -1) {
                    mark = in.nextInt();

                    while (mark <= -2 || mark >= 101){
                    System.out.println("Error: Enter Valid Input Type: "
                                + "Numbers from 0 - 100 for Marks. Or -1 to finish.");
                    in.nextInt();
                }


                    if (mark != -1) {
                        sum = sum + mark;
                        count++;

                        if (count == 1) {
                            largest = mark;
                            smallest = mark;

                        } else {
                            if (mark > largest) {
                                largest = mark;
                            }
                            if (mark < smallest) {
                                smallest = mark;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    if (mark >= 0 && mark <= 29) {
                        rangeOne++;
                    } else if (mark >= 30 && mark <= 39) {
                        rangeTwo++;
                    } else if (mark >= 40 && mark <= 69) {
                        rangeThree++;
                    } else if (mark >= 70 && mark <= 100) {
                        rangeFour++;
                    }
                }
            }



            System.out.print("0-29: ");
            for (int i = 0; i < rangeOne; i++) {
                System.out.print("*");
            }

            System.out.println();
            System.out.print("30-39: ");
            for (int i = 0; i < rangeTwo; i++) {
                System.out.print("*");
            }

            System.out.println();
            System.out.print("40-69: ");
            for (int i = 0; i < rangeThree; i++) {
                System.out.print("*");
            }

            System.out.println();
            System.out.print("70-100: ");
            for (int i = 0; i < rangeFour; i++) {
                System.out.print("*");
            }

            System.out.println("");
            if (count > 0) {
                System.out.println("Largest mark is: " + largest);
            } else {
                System.out.println("No data");
            }
            if (count > 0) {
                System.out.println("Smallest mark is: " + smallest);
            } else {
                System.out.println("No data");
            }
            if (count > 0) {
                double average = sum / count;
                System.out.println("Average marks: " + average);
            } else {
                System.out.println("No data");
            }

            if (count > 0) {
                System.out.println(rangeOne + rangeTwo + rangeThree + rangeFour
                        + " Total Number of Students");
            } else {
                System.out.println("No data");
            }

            {
//                if (mark >= rangeThree || mark <= rangeFour)
                System.out.println(rangeThree + rangeFour + " Number of Student Passed"
                        + " - (40 Marks or Above)");

//                else {
//            System.out.println("No data"); 
//        }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hello.

I am running into two problems when it comes to my code.

The first being that when integers are entered and then a non-integer is entered, instead of displaying an error and allowing the user to continue, the program will crash. With this, if I enter a non-integer, then integers, it will work, until I enter a second non-integer. Once again, the program crashes in this case.

---

### Example

- a
- 101
- -2
- a (Crash happens here)

Or

- 101
- a (Crash happens here)

---

The second problem being, that the smallest and largest numbers display correctly. However, I want the highest possible to be 100, if say 102 is entered, the number shouldn't be displayed. However, if I enter 102, the number does display. This is the same for smallest, where the smallest possible number is 0, if say -3 is entered, the number shouldn't display. However, if I enter -3, the number does display.

---

### **Example**

- 0 (Want this to display as lowest)
- 20
- 30
- -5 (Will display has lowest)
- 6
- 100 (Want this to display as highest)
- 78
- 106 (Will display has highest)

---

- Lowest is -5 (Want it to be 0)
- Highest is 106 (Want it to be 100

---

Help is appreciated.

Thanks. :)

Comment: With the case of "a" you can handle it using `NumberFormatException`. If such occurs then you can do your further handling. Same with `-1` as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid such exceptions by carefully handling them. What you can do is put the code or your logic in `try` block and in the `catch` block you can do something like:

```
catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {
   System.out.println("Please enter only numbers");
   in = sc.nextInt();
}
```

That'd be helpful to handle the alphabets as well in your code.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you are not assigning `mark` any value. It should be `mark = nextInt();` right after Scanner initialization.

Coming to your problems : 
1) Yes, only integers are expected to be fed by the user. If anything other than integers are provided then`java.util.InputMismatchException`  will be throw which you should handle in 

`try{<your code>} 
catch(InputMismatchException)`

block.

2) Code formatting - move all of your business logic which calculates smallest and greatest numbers to a private method.

```
private void printSmallestAndLargestNumber(int marks)
```

And avoid using so many if, else conditions. Its difficult to read.

The behavior which you are explaining in problem 2), I am getting worse than that. Please correct your code and make sure that you ran it with the input set you are providing.

Answer (score 0):

For your first problem, just move the first while condition at this position (after the second while condition)

```
while (mark != -1) {
         while (!in.hasNextInt()) {
                        System.out.println("Input not valid");
                        in.next();
                    }
         mark = in.nextInt();
```

For the second problem is due to your if condition for largest and smallest value. your code:

```
if (count == 1) {
                            largest = mark;
                            smallest = mark;

                        } else {
                            if (mark > largest) {
                                largest = mark;
                            }
                            if (mark < smallest) {
                                smallest = mark;
                            }
                        }
```

In the else section, you must add an if to check if the value is between 0 - 100 and the result is:

```
   if (count == 1) {
                                largest = mark;
                                smallest = mark;

                            } else {
                                if(mark >= 0 && mark <= 100){
                                    if (mark > largest) {
                                        largest = mark;
                                    }
                                    if (mark < smallest) {
                                        smallest = mark;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
```